# How to create a drop shadow with image

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a drop shadow on hover. This is the code I have written. The problem is when the I move mouse over the div, it glows but when I move the mouse over the image, the glow disappears.

```
<style>

#engines {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#engines div {
    float: left;
    width: 110px;
    height: 130px;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

#engines div img {
    margin: 5px 0 0 15px;
}


</style>

<script>
    $('document').ready(function() {
        $("#engines").children().hover(function() {
            $(this).css("box-shadow", "3px 3px 4px #000");
        });

        $("#engines").children().mouseout(function() {
            $(this).css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 0px #000");
        });

    });
</script>


</head>

<div id="engines">
    <div id="engine1">
        <img
            src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Mercedes_V6_DTM_Rennmotor_1996.jpg"
            width="80px" height="100px" />Dibya
    </div>

</div>
```

This is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sLytQ/)

Comment: Create a CSS class with the shadow and use [jQuery addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) on the mouseenter , it will then be persistent, and mouseleave to remove the class (removeClass) to remove the shadow

Comment: Is this an effect you want to apply individually to more similar engine items, such as `#engine2`, `#engine3`, etc... as in a gallery? I think you should clarify this for @BenM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `float: left` definition to `#engines` so that the containing `<div>` element will occupy some height, and then use the second function in the `hover()` function. Your updated code should look like this:

**CSS:**

```
#engines {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

#engines div {
    float: left;
    width: 110px;
    height: 130px;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

#engines div img {
    margin: 5px 0 0 15px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#engines").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("box-shadow", "3px 3px 4px #000");
}, function() {  
    $(this).css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 0px #000");
});
```

Here's an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLytQ/1/)

You should read over the [`hover()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/). Note that it can accept two handler functions in the argument list, one called when the hover begins, and one when it ends.

Of course, you could always use the `:hover` pseudo-class for the `#engines` by adding the following CSS alone:

```
#engines:hover {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLytQ/3/) showing the CSS method in action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:hover` pseudoclass:

```
#engines img:hover{
box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px black;
}
```

Comment: No need to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, that's what `hover` was created for. It can accept two handler functions...

Comment: Very true, references to mouseenter and mouseleave removed

Answer (score 0):

Trye this updated fiddle. You can use the find() method to get all children: http://jsfiddle.net/sLytQ/2/

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $("#engines").find('*').hover(function() {
            $('#engine1').css("box-shadow", "3px 3px 4px #000");
    });

    $("#engines").find('*').mouseout(function() {
            $('#engine1').css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 0px #000");
    });
});
```

Comment: If you don't stop propagation on the event, there should be no requirement to bind it to all children of `#engines`. They will all propagate up to the parent anyway...

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('document').ready(function() {
    $("#engine1").children().hover(function() {
        $(this).css("box-shadow", "3px 3px 4px #000");
    });

    $("#engine1").children().mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 0px #000");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
    $("#engines").hover(function() {
        $(this).css("box-shadow", "3px 3px 4px #000");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 0px #000");
    }
    );


});
</script>
```